# Wordpress Woocommerce trying to filter sale items only in a particular category

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

I have a wordpress site using woocommerce.

I am trying to use filter the products using WP_query to show just 4 products which are on sale, and which are also only in a certain category.

I am using meta_query to only filter in the sale products, and tax_query to filter the category.

I am struggling to get the loop to work using both tax_query and meta_query, although either of those without the other are working fine.

(I have also tried using 'product_cateogory' => 'skateboard-footwear' in the arguments, but the result is the same).

Here's the code:

```
$args = array( 
                      'post_type'  => 'product',
                      'orderby'     => 'date',
                      'order'       => 'desc',
                      'posts_per_page' => '4',
                      'meta_query'  => array(
                        array(
                          'key'     => '_sale_price',
                          'value'   => 0,
                          'compare' => '>',
                          'type'    => 'numeric'
                          )
                        ),
                      'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => 'skateboard-footwear',
                            'operator'  => 'IN'
                            )
                        )
                    );


                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         $args = array( 
                  'post_type'  => 'product',
                  'orderby'     => 'date',
                  'order'       => 'desc',
                  'posts_per_page' => '4',
                  'meta_query'  => array(
                    array(
                      'key'     => '_sale_price',
                      'value'   => 0,
                      'compare' => '>',
                      'type'    => 'numeric'
                      )
                    ),
     array( // Variable products type
        'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
        'value'         => 0,
        'compare'       => '>',
        'type'          => 'numeric'
    ),
                  'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                        'field'     => 'id',
                        'terms'     => '27',
                        'operator'  => 'IN'
                        )
                    )
                );
```

Need to add one more array thats specified min variation sale price and then after use tax_query. And also use product category by its id.